# Handling big data from parsing websites

Tags: data-processing, bigdata

I want to parse a huge website and build a dictionary. Basically, for every page, which is coupled to a few meta characteristics (name, date, etc), I want to store the frequency of word occurrences. Thus maintaining a list of all words like so:

```
       the   a  dog  kat ...
site1   5    10  1   0
site2   3    1   0   4
```

Since this will be a huge list I was wondering about the best way to store this. I was thinking of working in java. I read about mapReduce. Would that be appropriate here or should I use sql? I'd be happy with any reference or concrete suggestion that overcomes the problem of storing a huge file on my disk.

Comment: This is a very broad question and it really depends what you define as big data. If you have less than 100 million rows a well configured MySQL server should be easily able to store your data and process your queries. If your data is bigger than 100 million rows you should have a look at the NoSQL databases and their capabilities.

Comment: Interesting. It would be a news website, so sql might be a better approach. You wouldn't happen to know of an overview of systems and their limitations. I'm guessing an sql system (especially if stored online), would be difficult to retrieve the data to build a model on.

Comment: This article compares different SQL and NoSQL databases: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/01/sql-vs-nosql-db/. Just for comparison, StackOverflow using Microsoft SQL server, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network